In the Spring Boot test, the Redis container does not start
To create a testing environment that closely resembles the production environment in Spring Boot, we used Test Containers.
While the MySQL test container worked well, we encountered an issue where the Redis container wouldn't start.
Redis Container
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer;
import org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.Wait;
import org.testcontainers.utility.DockerImageName;

@SuppressWarnings("NonAsciiCharacters")
final class RedisContainerProvider {

    private static final DockerImageName DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME = DockerImageName.parse("redis:7.0");
    private static final Integer REDIS_PORT = 6379;
    private static final GenericContainer<?> REDIS_CONTAINER;

    static {
        REDIS_CONTAINER = new GenericContainer<>(DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME)
            .withExposedPorts(REDIS_PORT)
            .waitingFor(Wait.forHealthcheck());

        REDIS_CONTAINER.start();

        System.setProperty("spring.data.redis.host", REDIS_CONTAINER.getHost());
        System.setProperty("spring.data.redis.port", String.valueOf(REDIS_CONTAINER.getMappedPort(REDIS_PORT)));
    }
}

application.yml
    redis:
      port: 6379
      host: localhost
      password: password

The exception message indicates that it's a "Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:6379."
Exception log
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to localhost/<unresolved>:6379
    at app//io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:78)
    at app//io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:56)
    at app//io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisClient.getConnection(AbstractRedisClient.java:350)
    at app//io.lettuce.core.RedisClient.connect(RedisClient.java:216)
    at app//org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.StandaloneConnectionProvider.lambda$getConnection$1(StandaloneConnectionProvider.java:112)
    at java.base@17.0.11/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at app//org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.StandaloneConnectionProvider.getConnection(StandaloneConnectionProvider.java:112)
    at app//org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$ExceptionTranslatingConnectionProvider.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1531)
    ... 166 more
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:6379
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:946)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:337)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:776)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)


The Redis container isn't starting, so I understand that Spring is trying to create a bean using the Redis host and port specified in application.yml, which is causing a connection issue.
Even when trying to use @DynamicPropertySource, the same exception occurs.
@SuppressWarnings("NonAsciiCharacters")
final class RedisContainerProvider {

    private static final DockerImageName DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME = DockerImageName.parse("redis:7.0");
    private static final Integer REDIS_PORT = 6379;
    private static final GenericContainer<?> REDIS_CONTAINER;

    static {
        REDIS_CONTAINER = new GenericContainer<>(DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME)
            .withExposedPorts(REDIS_PORT)
            .waitingFor(Wait.forHealthcheck());

        REDIS_CONTAINER.start();

//      System.setProperty("spring.data.redis.host", REDIS_CONTAINER.getHost());
//      System.setProperty("spring.data.redis.port", String.valueOf(REDIS_CONTAINER.getMappedPort(REDIS_PORT)));
    }

    @DynamicPropertySource
     static void registerRedisProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.data.redis.host", REDIS_CONTAINER::getHost);
        registry.add("spring.data.redis.port", () -> REDIS_CONTAINER.getMappedPort(REDIS_PORT)
                                                                    .toString());
    }

}

Reference Document

https://java.testcontainers.org/test_framework_integration/manual_lifecycle_control/#singleton-containers

have a nice day - kevin

I don't get this RedisContainerProvider why is there an @Test in there? Why is the @DynamicPropertySource private and how and where does this class come into play? I see it nowhere being used.

It looks like the method I added to check if the Redis container is running might not be suitable, so I’ll delete it right away. The private modifier seems to have been added by mistake as well, so I’ll remove that too.

@M.Deinum
I want to use the Singleton pattern to create the test container only once, and I’ve implemented the code as shown above.
This approach worked successfully with the MySQL container, but it failed with the Redis container.
Reference document : https://java.testcontainers.org/test_framework_integration/manual_lifecycle_control/#singleton-containers

Without showing the code where the RedisContainerProvider is going to be used it will be impossible to answer. Also the @DynamicPropertySource doesn't do anything if not on a test or configuration class.

The @Configuration annotation turned out to be the solution for me.
The RedisContainerProvider runs only once when the base class is loaded. After that, the container continues to operate even if it's not used by other classes.
Therefore, RedisContainerProvider is not used by other classes, and that’s why I didn’t include the code for it.

If it's not too much trouble, could you provide an Answer suggesting to add the @Configuration annotation? I’m planning to accept it!
Thank you for your hard work.

If you're using Spring Boot, you should consider following the recommendations in the Spring Boot documentation for Testcontainers integration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/reference/testing/testcontainers.html.
